# copy rows from one sheet to another with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a macro that will search a List sheet for different counties and then paste the entire row onto the current sheet. I have a worksheet for each person (named Mark, John, etc.) and each person is assigned several counties. Mark has three counties, listed in cells J1:L1, which I've named as a range (MyCounties). I need a macro that will look through Sheet "List" column "I" for each of those counties and copy the entire row onto Sheet "Mark" starting at "A4". I'm using a modified macro I found on here, but I must be doing something wrong. It is currently giving me an error "Application defined or object defined error" in regards to `Set Rng = Sheets("List").Range([I4], Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

```
Sub NewSheetData()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Dim Rng As Range, rCell As Range

Set Rng = Sheets("List").Range([I4], Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each rCell In Range("MyCounties")
    On Error Resume Next
        With Rng
            .AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:=rCell.Value
            .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
                Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
Next rCell

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: put `Sheets("List").` in front of the second `Range` in that line.

Comment: I did that. It now looks like `Set Rng = Sheets("List").Range([I4], Sheets("List").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))` I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: put the `[I4]` in quotes and not brackets `Set Rng = Sheets("List").Range("I4", Sheets("List").Range("I" & Sheets("List").Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

Comment: If `MyCounties` is a named range on the Mark worksheet, what is the named range on the John worksheet? Are these named ranges with worksheet-level scope?

Comment: I will rename the ranges to be MarkCounties, JohnCounties, etc. once I get the code working. I think they are worksheet-level. I highlighted the cells I wanted, then typed the name in the name box in the upper left hand corner.

Comment: So the code runs without error now, but its not bringing all the rows over. My named range is J1:L1, and is Fresno, Kings, then Tulare. When I run the macro, there should be 7 rows with Fresno, 1 with Kings, and 2 with Tulare. Instead, I get the two Tulare results first, then 5 Fresno results, and no Kings.

Comment: Look to your data and make sure there are no unprintable characters like trailing spaces or mistypes n either list.

Comment: Ok, checked the data, its good. Retyped it just to make sure. Figured out the issue, but don't know how to fix it. So it's bringing over all 7 of Fresno starting at A4, then starts at A4 again for the one Kings, then again starts at A4 for Tulare. How do I make it go down to the first blank row and paste there?

Comment: You've created named ranges with workbook scope. Instead of thinking '*they are worksheet-level*', you should go into Formulas, Defined Names and find out. Typically, defined names are generated with workbook scope but if you want to use the same name for different named ranges on different worksheets then you would use worksheet scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will need to be adjusted to accommodate your named ranges and worksheet names. It currently uses named ranges with worksheet scope from each worksheet.

```
Sub NewSheetData()
    Dim w As Long, sWSs As Variant, vCrit As Variant, rw As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    sWSs = Array("Mark", "John", "etc")

    For w = LBound(sWSs) To UBound(sWSs)
        With Worksheets(sWSs(w))
            vCrit = .Range("MyCounties").Value2
            rw = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 4)
        End With

         With Worksheets("List")
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Range(.Cells(4, "I"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        .Cells.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(sWSs(w)).Cells(rw, "A")
                    End If
                End With
            End With
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
   Next w

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

This uses the values from each worksheet's *MyCounties* named range as an array of criteria for .AutoFilter. using an array as criteria requires the `Operator:=xlFilterValues` parameter. It also checks to make sure that there are filtered values to copy before copying them.

Comment: This code is fantastic. Works like a charm for all of these easy ones. One more question, though. For larger areas like Los Angeles County, it gets split up between 5 people, who each take different cities within that county, and within LA itself, take different zip codes. Is it possible to search for matching county and city (for all cities not LA), as well as for Los Angeles (city) and zip code? County is column "I", City is column "G", and Zip is column "H". So "Christina" would have within LA county cities of Acton, Burbank, etc. and also LA (city) zip codes of 90008, 90016, etc.

Comment: I could either use a helper sheet to list all these, say Sheet "LA County" where A1 would be persons name, A2 would list counties (Just LA in this example), A3 (and B3, C3, etc. however many cities she has total) would list cities within LA county, and A4 would list zip codes within LA city.

Comment: When using an array as criteria for AutoFilter, you cannot have a `Criteria2` parameter but you can add additional columns for filtering. If you want to expand on this solution then you will need to close this off and ask a new question. There are simply too many things to consider for this to be dealt in comments. Provide your current code, sample data and show the results you expect. No screenshots; no one wants to waste time retyping sample data.

Comment: Using this code today, I noticed that on the "List" sheet, it doesn't copy row 4. It copies everything else that matches the criteria, but that row it skips, for some reason.

Comment: AutoFilter requires a header row no matter whether it has column text labels or not. That's why the code offsets one row to  look for filtered results. I assumed from your original code that the header row was in row 4.  If your header row is in row 3 and your data starts in row 4 then change `.Cells(4, "I")` to `.Cells(3, "I")`.

Comment: Ok, that worked perfectly. Thank you. I've taken your advice and started a new question for the more difficult filters here:    [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683835/copy-rows-with-multiple-sub-criteria)    Would you mind looking at it and telling me what I'm doing wrong? I've edited the code a bit to fit the situation.

Answer (score 0):

may be your `EntireRow` is copying rows whose first column is blank

you could use `UsedRange` property of worksheet object to get the last used row

furthermore you'd better place `With Rng` oustide the loop, since it doesn't change with it

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewSheetData()
    Dim Rng As Range, rCell As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Sheets("List")
        Set Rng = .Range("I4", .Range("I" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Rng
        For Each rCell In Range("MyCounties")
            .AutoFilter , Field:=1, Criteria1:=rCell.Value
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy _
            Sheets("Sheeta2").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheeta2").UsedRange.Rows(Sheets("Sheeta2").UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row).Offset(1)
        Next
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When I run this code, there are no errors, but it also doesn't find anything.

Comment: As per your explanations, this code has to be launched with "Mark" sheet as the active one